# Copy a single cell and paste to a location determined by adjacent cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a value in cell H17 on worksheet 1.  It is next to a dropdown list of values in cell G17.  I would like to copy and paste H17 into the adjacent location in column C where G17 matches a value in column B.  This is all done on the same worksheet.

I have't tried any VBA methods yet but have spent far too long trying to find the solution.

[image: Spreadsheet example]

Comment: Add some screen shots of what you are looking at. Without that, your question is very difficult to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some VBA code which should do what you want:

```
Sub CopyConditional()
    Dim monthRange As Range
    Set monthRange = Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown))

    For Each cell In monthRange.Cells
        If cell.Value = Range("G17").Value Then
            cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Range("H17").Value
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

This will first find all the months (assuming no gaps in your table), then loop through them and compare to the value in G17. If they match it will copy the value from H17 to the adjacent cell.

Comment: Be advised that this will only work for one value of H17. If you want to move values consecutively, this isn't a solution.

Comment: Thank, but not quite.  I intend to have a submit button to run the macro.  This will allow the user to select the month from a drop down list in G17 input their pay in G18 and submit it to column C next to the appropriate month.  i have now added a screenshot to original post.

Comment: I've edited my answer now that I better understand what you wanted to do.